# Generalization of zero-diagonal square matrices to linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Which linear operators in Banach or Hilbert spaces (e.g., partial differential operators or some other operators in functional spaces) are generalizations of square matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ such that $a_{kk}=0$ for all $k$? That is, all elements on the main diagonal of the square matrix $A$ are zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the set of $n \times n$ matrices with vanishing diagonal completely fails to be closed under similarity, the condition of having a vanishing diagonal can't even make sense as a coordinate-independent condition on linear transformations on a finite-dimensional vector space. At best, for a Hilbert space (finite- or infinite-dimensional) $H$ *together* with fixed orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}$, you can consider the set of all $A \in B(H)$ such that $\left\langle e_k, A e_k \right\rangle=0$ for each $k$, which might conceivably be a sensible thing to do for Hilbert spaces with canonical orthonormal basis, e.g. $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ or $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

That said, the set of $n \times n$ *real* matrices with vanishing diagonal contains the vector space of skew-adjoint real matrices, which generalise to skew-adjoint operators, bounded or densely defined, on a real Hilbert space, e.g. $\tfrac{d}{dx}$ on $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R},dx)$.